Are there arbitrarily long runs of consecutive numbers not expressed as $a^2 + b^3 + c^5$
When $\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{j}+\frac{1}{k} < 1$ then it's easy to see that there are arbitrarily long runs of consecutive numbers NOT expressed as $a^i + b^j + c^k$ for integer positive a,b,c.
The simplest case when  $\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{j}+\frac{1}{k} > 1$ is $a^2 + b^3 + c^5$. And it seems that there exists the maximum possible length of a run of consecutive numbers NOT expressed in this way.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Probably unknown. However, there is a real $1 > \delta > 0$   such that the count $E(x)$ of   exceptions, the count of numbers up to large positive $x$  that are not the sum of $a^2 + b^3 + c^5$  for positive integers $a,b,c$    obeys $E(x) < x^{1-\delta} .$  See chapter 8 in the second edition of Vaughan, The Hardy-Littlewood Method. This is Theorem 8.1 on page 128.

Vaughan's original article on this was in 1980, https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-41.3.516      There are several more recent articles,    some in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28203-9
